# jQuery rendering a link to chat system

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building an web app for my client and it involves a chat system where users can communicate with each other.
Now what my client wants me to do, is that if user has send an link to another user using this chat system,
it should automatically render it as an link (within a tag).

Now I can return a normal text if it's an regular text, but if it's a link, it currently returns [object Object].
The regular expression itself works, I have tested it out, the only part I'm having trouble is to actually render
the link.

Here's my function to test if it's a link:

**functions.js**

```
function isAValidUrl(data)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp('(([\\w]+:)?//)?(([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+(:([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\\d\\‌​w][-\\d\\w]{0,253}[\\d\\w]\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}(:[\\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)*(\\‌​?(&?([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)?');
    if(!pattern.test(data)) {
        return data;
    } else {

         return $('<a>').attr('href', data.message).text(data.message);
    }
}
```

And here's a part of my Chat.js where I'm using that function

**chat.js**

```
function render() {

    var html = [], messages = $self.data('messages');
    var escaper = $('<div/>');
    for (var i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        html.push(
            '<div class="media chat-message" data-message-id="' + messages[i].id + '">' +
            '<div class="message-meta"><span class="sender-name">' + messages[i].sender_name + '</span><span class="stamp pull-right" data-stamp="' + messages[i].created_at + '"></span></div>' +
            '<div class="media-body">' +
            '<div class="message-text">' + escaper.text(isAValidUrl(messages[i].message)).html() + '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>'
        );
    }
    $self.find('.message-container').html(html.join('')).end().find('.stamp[data-stamp]').timeAgo();
    clearInterval(timeAgoTimer);
    timeAgoTimer = setInterval(function () {
        $self.find('.stamp[data-stamp]').timeAgo();
    }, 60000);
    return $self.chatBox('scrollToBottom');
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery this plugin works well and covers almost every possible situtation...

https://github.com/SoapBox/jQuery-linkify

As discussed in the comments, call linkify on the element that contains the text you want to "linkify", not on the text itself.

```
$('.message-text').linkify();
```

Comment: This looks pretty handy, thanks for sharing it. Although it didn't work with those chat messages even when I added a data-linkify="this"attribute to the message text class.

Comment: Can you show me how you tried to instantiate it? You have to apply it to the element that contains the text, not the text itself. `$('.message-text').linkify();

Answer (score 0):

You're treating your parameter inconsistently in the function -- is it an object with a property called `message` that's a string?  Or is it just a string?  If it's just a string, then this will work:

```
function isAValidUrl(data)
{
    var pattern = new RegExp('(([\\w]+:)?//)?(([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+(:([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\\d\\‌​w][-\\d\\w]{0,253}[\\d\\w]\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}(:[\\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)*(\\‌​?(&?([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)?');
    if(!pattern.test(data)) {
        return data;
    } else {

         return $('<a>').attr('href', data).text(data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a text to div and then call .html() with the below code

```
var escaper = $('<div/>');    
escaper.text(isAValidUrl(messages[i].message)).html()
```

You should set .html() than use .text() as if its a  link it would return an object.

```
'<div class="message-text">' + escaper.html(isAValidUrl(messages[i].message)).html()+ '</div>' +
```

Demo

```js
function isAValidUrl(data) {
  var pattern = new RegExp('(([\\w]+:)?//)?(([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+(:([\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\\d\\‌​w][-\\d\\w]{0,253}[\\d\\w]\\.)+[\\w]{2,4}(:[\\d]+)?(/([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)*(\\‌​?(&?([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\\d\\w]|%[a-fA-f\\d]{2,2})*)?');
  if (!pattern.test(data)) {
    return data;
  } else {

    return $('<a>').attr('href', data).text(data);
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = [];
  var messages = ["no link", "http://www.test.com"];
  var msg = "http://www.test.com";
  var div = $('<div/>');
  for (var i = messages.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    html.push('<div class="message-text">' + div.html(isAValidUrl(messages[i])).html() + '</div>');
  }
  $('body').append(html);

});
```

```css
.message-text {
  background: #eee;
  color: #555;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```